# I am trying OpenShift origin, I cannot create application

Tags: openshift-origin

I am trying OO on a RHEL Atomic Host. I spun up OO master as a container following this guide https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html

After attaching a shell to the Master Container, I cannot deploy an app.

```
# oc new-app openshift/deployment-example
error: can't look up Docker image "openshift/deployment-example": Internal  error occurred: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/htt p: request canceled while waiting for connection error: no match for "openshift/deployment-example"

The 'oc new-app' command will match arguments to the following types:

1. Images tagged into image streams in the current project or the 'openshift' project
 - if you don't specify a tag, we'll add ':latest'
2. Images in the Docker Hub, on remote registries, or on the local Docker engine
3. Templates in the current project or the 'openshift' project
4. Git repository URLs or local paths that point to Git repositories

 --allow-missing-images can be used to point to an image that does not exist yet.

See 'oc new-app -h' for examples.
```

The host needs proxy to access Internet. I have configured proxy in /etc/sysconfig/docker and that is how I could pull the origin image in the same place.

I have tried setting proxy for master and node with luck
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/http_proxies.html

Comment: Bug report here: https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/7256

Comment: This is likely because you need proxy settings set on the master processes to be able to access those images.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your proxy is terminating the connection. you can test by creating an internal registry, push image to that and then use 
"oc new-app your.internal.registry/openshift/deployment-example"